# How to add pagination to carousel bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have the next carousel:

[Fraction Template carousel](http://fraction.orange-themes.com/gallery/vim-graeco-prompta-ocurreret-ei/)

In my case, the news has 33 photos and when i set them to the carousel, the size of the thumb bar rises to 3-4 rows. How do i do to make pagination in one row to the thumb bar?
When i click on the left/right button, the actual photo set in the main bar wourld be selected in the thumb bar.

Comment: I think if you use another jQuery plugin for slider, will be better,don't try to reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: The problem is the page that i have to maintain is done with that template :(.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean, you need the same UI as that template (that you linked)?

Comment: Just check this amazing plugins, http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html, https://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-image-and-video-gallery-with-thumbnails/

Comment: Can you help me with the jquery code? At least, i can that when i tap a photo from the thumb, it set in the main bar and sleect and center the photo selected in the thumb bar, is that possible?? Thanks!

Comment: So, sounds like you still want to use bootstrap's carousel, right?

Comment: Yes, i need to use with the template that i put in these html link. Anyway, i already send a mail to the support template! We'll see what they have to say to us.